# Как найти элемент на странице Python?

Tags: python, requests

Нужно найти имя элемента, которое генерируется каждый раз и отправить пост запросом.

[image: 1]

Насколько я понимаю, этот скрипт генерирует имя элемента.

[image: 2]

Comment: что запрос на указанный (.../...php) адрес возвращает?

Comment: @jfs генерирует имя элемента

Comment: если вы уже нашли имя элемента, то в чём вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

```
from urllib import request as req

page = req.urlopen("https://ua.siteground.com/637eda5/2705a8.php").read().decode("utf-8")
print(page)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @tellst1 можете предоставить часть исходного кода страницы или ссылку на веб-сайт с указанием нужной формы?

Comment: https://ua.siteground.com/login.htm

Comment: @tells1 `page = req.urlopen("https://ua.siteground.com/637eda5/2705a8.php").read().decode("utf-8")` и затем `print(page)`

Comment: @jfs спасибо за напоминание, перенес.